# SQL find team that only contains specified 2 users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `team_members` with this structure and contents:

```
+---------+---------+
| team_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |      18 |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       7 |
+---------+---------+
|       3 |      18 |
+---------+---------+
```

What i am trying to do is to find a team that only contains 2 users and this users are supplied by me (in this case users with id 7 and 18). Unfortunately, i am having no ideas about how to make this query properly. I have tried something like

```
SELECT a.team_uid
FROM team_members a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT team_uid, user_id, COUNT(*) cnt_team
    FROM team_members
    GROUP BY team_uid
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
) b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Case statement` in `Having` clause and `Count` only the required user_id's. Try this.

```
select teamid from yourtable
group by teamid
having count(case when userid=7 then 1 end)=1
and    count(case when userid=18 then 1 end)=1
and count(1)=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Something to think about (and assuming a PK on team_id,user_id)...

```
SELECT x.*, COUNT(*),SUM(user_id IN(7,18)) FROM my_table x GROUP BY team_id;
```

Comment: Your query seems to miss the check that specific team consists only from 2 users

Answer (score 1):

A couple more ways to do this (where `$id1` and `$id2` are the users in question):

```
SELECT team_id
  FROM team_members
 GROUP BY team_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
   AND MIN(user_id) = LEAST($id1,$id2)
   AND MAX(user_id) = GREATEST($id1,$id2)
```

[See SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/615f9f/2) with values of 7 and 18 for `$id1` and `$id2`. I am using `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` in case it's not known which is the higher and which is the lower (for example, if they're coming from user input).

```
SELECT team_id
  FROM team_members
 GROUP BY team_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(user_id ORDER BY user_id) = ('7,18')
```

[See SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/615f9f/4). Again, if it isn't known which is the higher and which is the lower, then this might be written as (the `ORDER BY` in `GROUP_CONCAT()` would be unnecessary):

```
SELECT team_id
  FROM team_members
 GROUP BY team_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) IN ('$id1,$id2','$id2,$id1')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
select team_id
  from team_members
 group by team_id
having sum(user_id not in(7, 18)) = 0
```

Example above assumes you want teams with only users 7 or 18 (no others, but not necessarily both).

If you want teams with BOTH users 7 and 18, and no others, you can use:

```
select team_id
  from team_members
 group by team_id
having sum(user_id not in(7, 18)) = 0
   and sum(user_id in(7, 18)) = 2
```